# Split string in TCL

Tags: string, split, tcl, f5

I'm coding an iRule on our F5 server but I'm a complete beginner when it comes to TCL.

I have a `HTTP::host` variable that contain a hostname in the following format: `application-dev.com`

All I'm trying to do is split this string where the hyphen occurs and set the first and second sections to separate variables. So I would end up with this:

```
variable1 = application
variable2 = dev.com
```

I've gotten this far:

```
set hostSections [split [HTTP::host] "-"]
```

But can't find any information on how to assign the sections to seperate variables

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`lindex`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm) (list index) for older versions of Tcl:

```
set variable1 [lindex $hostSections 0]
set variable2 [lindex $hostSections 1]
```

Since lists are 0-indexed, `0` will indicate the first element of the list.

In Tcl 8.5 and later, you can use [`lassign`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm) which makes things shorter:

```
lassign [split [HTTP::host] "-"] variable1 variable2
```

Both ways stores the values in the variable names `variable1` and `variable2`.

Comment: For older versions it was also common to abuse foreach as an lassign: `foreach {var1 var2 var3} [split [HTTP::host] -] {break}`

Comment: @schlenk Nice, never came across that one :)